# How many questions would you need to retag (for burnination / tag deletion) before it would be considered offensive or "abuse"?

Tags: feature-request, tags, retag-request

**For example:** There were nine questions with the tag [flex-4.5](/questions/tagged/flex-4.5), and I've been doing my best to retag such posts with their proper [flex4.5](/questions/tagged/flex4.5) tag.  But at what point (how many questions) should I ask (in meta) about retagging before doing it myself?

In this case, I figured as it was just an obvious typo I'd fix it myself; but people keep using the tag, so I might have to request blacklist so it's not used...

**My Questions:**

1. How many questions with an erroneous tag must exist before it would be "too many questions to self-moderate" within any sane definition?
2. What would you do for the example tag above, what is the best solution to request?  Burnination, Blacklist, Synonym (probably not for a typo....), Merger?

Comment: Sounds like you want a tag synonym not a retag. If it's a mistake people are going to continue to make a tag synonym is superior.

Comment: Is it though?  The tag is a typo, wouldn't a synonym be a bad thing?  Also, are there two types of synonyms?  Because sometimes I see both tags listed, and other times I just see the suggested tag; with "also: mytag" highlighted.  The former being a good solution for this problem.  And yes, people keep making this mistake; if you check my StackOverflow activity, you'll see that I ***just*** fixed yet another one of these.